# How to get branch name in jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write my first Jenkins shared library and I'm struggling with something basic - getting the branch name.

I could do:

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
```

However, that requires a checkout. Would it be possible to get the branch name (for both multibranch and freestyle) pipeline projects? I know I'll be using git, but I would like to avoid doing a checkout (until it is necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The GIT_BRANCH environment variable should give you what you want. It won't work in pipeline until Jenkins 2.60 and upgraded pipeline model definition plugin.

Comment: When I try it on the latest jenkins (2.73.2) and up to date plugins, I get 'null' in the pipeline script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pipeline job, you can

- Capture object returned from scm checkout
- Reference environment variable

---

```
pipeline {
    // ...
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // capture scm variables
                    def scmVars = checkout scm
                    String branch = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH

                    // or use the environment variable
                    branch = env.GIT_BRANCH
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Environment variable reference.](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)

Comment: Thanks, but could I do it _without_ the checkout?

Comment: You can also use the Jenkins provided environment variable `env.GIT_BRANCH`.

Comment: From the tests I've run, it only works for multibranch pipeline plugin :(

Comment: For what it's worth, I would highly recommend the multibranch pipeline plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
 env.CHANGE_BRANCH ?: env.GIT_BRANCH ?: scm.branches[0]?.name?.split('/')[1] ?: 'UNKNOWN'
```

However, this requires me to approve several things in `In-Script Approvals` page.